# Showing that $A = \{\tan x \mid x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})\}$ is not bounded, without calculus.

Tags: trigonometry

I have to show that $A = \{\tan x \mid x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})\}$ is not bounded.

Since $\tan\colon (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) \to \mathbb R$ is surjective $\Rightarrow \tan((-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})) = \mathbb R$, we know that $\mathbb R$ is not bounded $\Rightarrow A$ not bounded. Is this correct? Any other solutions not involving calculus?

Comment: Your conditional statements are true, but I'm not sure about *correctess*. I'm afraid there might be circularity here. How do you know that $\text{im}(\tan)=\Bbb R$?

Comment: Your reasoning is circular.

Comment: What is your definition of $\tan$?

Comment: Its six x/cos x

Comment: Well since tan has codomain R and is surjective Im(tan) must be R, How to show that R is the domain of tan...than i dont know

Comment: @phi How do you know that your function $\tan$ is surjective?

Comment: well for every y in R the equation tan x = y has at least a solution in (-pi/2, pi/2), x = arctan y + kpi

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of $\sin, \cos$ and $\tan$ to show that the range of $\tan$ is $\mathbb{R}$! So $\cos x$ is the rpojection of the respective point on the unit circle onto the $x-$axis, $\sin x$ - onto the $y-$axis (you get this respective point $P_x$ by rotating the point $P_0(1,0)$ counterclockwise by $x$ radians). Take then the vertical line that is parallel to $y$-axis and contains $P_0(1,0)$. Take any point $P_{y_0}(1,y_0)$ from that line. Connect this point $P_{y_0}$ with (0,0). The segment you've got will intersect the unit circle at some point $P_\alpha$. It can easily be shown (it involves some obvious manipulations with triangles (similar triangles or whatever)) then that $y_0$ is equal to $\tan \alpha$, where $\alpha\in(-\frac\pi 2, \frac\pi 2)$ is the measure of the angle made up be the segment we've just drawn and the positive part of the $x$-axis. So since our $y_0$ was arbitrary, this shows that the range of $\tan$ is indeed the whole set of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For any $a \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, the mid point of $a$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ also belongs to $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.
Let $t = \tan(\frac{a}{2})$, we have:

$$\tan(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+a}{2})
=\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{a}{2}) = \frac{1+t}{1-t}
= \frac{(1+t)^2}{1-t^2} = \frac{1 + \frac{2t}{1+t^2}}{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}
= \frac{1 + \sin a}{\cos(a)} \ge 2\tan(a)
$$
So start with $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}) = 1$, we get

$$\begin{align}
\tan(\frac{3\pi}{8}) &= \tan(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}}{2}) \ge 2 \tan(\frac{\pi}{4}) = 2\\
\implies\tan(\frac{7\pi}{16}) &= \tan(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{3\pi}{8}}{2}) \ge 2 \tan(\frac{3\pi}{8}) \ge 2^2\\
&\;\vdots\\
\implies \tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2^n}) &=
\tan(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2} + (\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}})}{2}) \ge 2 \tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}) \ge 2^{n-2}\\
\end{align}$$
This implies $\tan(x)$ is unbounded above in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Since $\tan(-x) = -\tan(x)$, this also implies $\tan(x)$ is unbounded below on $(-\frac{\pi}{2},0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to me that the easiest approach is to show that there exists a left neighborhood of $\pi/2$  where $\sin$ is larger than, say, $1/2$, and $\cos$ is not bounded away from zero. How do you do that? The answer depends on your definition of the goniometric functions sin and cos. The ``baby'' approach implies continuity, so it leans on some hidden calculus.

But you could also show that the inequality $$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} > K$$ is solved in a left neighborhood of $\pi/2$ by putting $\cos x = X$, $\sin x = Y$, and using the fact that $X^2+Y^2=1$.

Anyway, I doubt that you have a definition that allows you to work with these inequalities without using any calculus idea.

Comment: I guess Calculus was developed to answer this kind of questions

Comment: Probably. And much depends on your level of satisfaction about rigor. I remember that my high school book claimed that the tangen function is clearly unbounded, since the denominator approaches zero while the numerator approaches one. And we, the students, were completely satisfied by this "proof".